# javascript function in confirmation button?

Tags: javascript

How to have a confirmation button in my codes below? (Yes - cancel)

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", "<script>alert('There is an exiting Insurance code. Are you sure do you want to Edit it?');</script>");
```

I tried this one but its not working..

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "key", "if(!confirm('There is an existing insurance code . Do you want to edit?'))return false;");
```

thanks!

Comment: Alert/Confirm/Prompt windows on load are horrible. Please don't use them.

Answer (score 2):

Use javascript [confirm](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) dialog instead of alert.

```
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("There is an exiting Insurance code. 
            Are you sure do you want to Edit it?")
    if (answer){
        alert("You clicked OK.");
    }
    else{
        alert("You clicked Cancel.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`confirm`](http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/javascript/ex_confirm.htm) function.

It's probably worth noting that usability principles often frown upon this

Edit Probably something along the lines of

```
if (confirm('There is an exiting Insurance code.' + "\n" + "Are you sure you want to Edit it?"))
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page));
```